# Did a New Zealand boy start eating normally after being treated by Iranian-Islamic traditional medicine?

Tags: medical-science, iran

In a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqvU9nJfjw0) broadcast from Iranian TV [Persian, English subtitles for first 1.5m], 7 years ago, it is claimed that a New Zealand boy, Solomon "Solly" Moss, started eating normally (**without any force and by its own will**) after being treated with Iranian-Islamic medicine, while doctors in Switzerland, Australia, New Zealand, US, etc. were unable to diagnose and treat the disease. In the video she says she spent over $100,000 on his son's treatment before meeting with the Iranian doctor, Dr Kherandish.

I couldn't find any content by googling the son's name or his mother's name (Lisa Krukziner), or his uncle's name (Andrew Krukziner).

In the video, pictures of the doctors' comments are shown. e.g. Dr. Reuben Jackson from the University of New South Wales or Dr. Jeff Jankelson (I am not sure about his surname).

I saw this video 4 years ago but I didn't know about Skeptics.SE then and I've searched for over 6 hours to verify the correctness of this claim but to no avail. I couldn't find even one non-Persian webpage/news about this claim.

It [seems](https://www.nzherald.co.nz/business/family-feud-shuts-burrito-stores-100-jobs-at-risk/C3HIJGFCLRCQFZW3WJL75SLAFA/) that this family really exist in New Zealand.

Did Solomon Moss start eating normally (without any force and by its own will) after being treated by Iranian-Islamic traditional medicine?

### Edit:

Because the video is in Persian, here is a summary of the narration:

- Her son was unable to eat anything, not even his mother's milk (when he was a baby), from birth to the year of treatment.
- Her son constantly vomited everything he ate.
- She had hired some nurses to force-feed her son by tying his hands and feet.
- In video the presenter say some doctors suggested to drill his stomach for transferring food into the son's stomach (this is called PEG Tube surgery in medicine).
- The Iranian doctor's treatment was decoction of a medicinal plant (that she shows that medicinal plant to the camera in the video)+ a little honey
- At the end of the video, her brother suggests setting up a hospital/center of Iranian medicine in New Zealand due to the effectiveness of this medicine and the inability of modern medicine.

Comment: I'm curious - how does the existence of an Australian business owner named Moss whose chain of burrito shops has outlets in Auckland, NZ, prove the existence of Solomon Moss and him being a New Zealander?

Comment: @tink I said __it seems__.

Comment: Just how exactly?

Comment: @tink It is the video claim. not mine.

Comment: The video dragged up the newspaper link? I didn't bother watching it ...

Comment: @tink No. Video say, a wealthy New Zealand family. Also at the end of the newspaper it says: _... he was returning to New Zealand from Sydney yesterday._

Answer (score 12):

The claim, as presented by the OP, is that Solomon Moss didn't start eating until miraculously cured. It is difficult for me to confirm that the video makes that claim, as stated, because I don't speak Persian/Farsi, and the limited English translations don't explicitly make that claim.

As a skeptic, the obvious issue with the claim is the [post hoc ergo propter hoc fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc). Even if every fact about the symptoms and signs were true as claimed, we don't know if the Iranian treatment was responsible for the improvement, whether other treatments were being pursued at the same time or whether the child was going to grow out of his illness no matter what the treatment. It would take a randomised controlled study to draw the conclusion that the Iranian treatment was responsible.

However, independently of that, the video's *own* evidence undermines the claim that the child was not eating.

An undated letter from a doctor, at 1m43s, says

> [image]
> He is eating food: meat vegies, potato 2-3 meals per day. He eats with a spoon but all his food is pureed by his mother. He vomits 3-4 times per day [...]

So, we was *eating* before the alleged cure. The issue was vomiting.

At 1m28s in the video, a letter from Dr Reuben Jackson, dated 18 December 2008, is shown.

> [image: Excerpt of letter from Dr Reuben Jackson]
>
> He has outgrown his cow's milk protein intolerance and is now having more fluid intake although at times it needs to be syringed [...] if anything, he rarely vomits these days.
>
> His reflux medication is 20mg Omeprazole [...]

Either this letter was written *before* the Iranian treatment, and shows the child was getting better without it, or it is *during/after* the Iranian treatment, and shows that the child was being treated concurrently with medicine and the credit can't be given to the Iranian treatment.

In conclusion, the evidence provided by the video itself undermines the claims that he was not eating before the treatment, and that the traditional Iranian treatment was responsible for his eventual return to health. Whether video actually made those claims is less clear.

Comment: I __assume__ the evidence shown in the video is fake with random names and text. I would like to find another source to make sure. For example, one can refer or ask those doctors or that family or any news reported about this claim that is probably filtered by search engines in my country.  Also, my bad phrasing and your hyper sensitivity to words reduced my meaning to "not eating at all", when what I and the video itself actually meant was "not being able to eat normally like everyone else". If the child was recovering without Iranian treatment, why did his mother come to Iran for treatment?

Comment: 1) If you assume some parts of the video are fake, why would assume any of it is true? 2) Dr Avi Lemberg and Dr Reuben Jackson are easy to confirm (LinkedIn, amongst others). 3) The issue of phrasing is normally dealt with by citing the actual claim. I don't see any where were they talk about "eating normally", but I don't speak Farsi. Can you quote the appropriate section?

Comment: 4) Why go to an Iranian doctor? Because she was visiting family in Iran? Because she was holidaying in Iran? Because she was scammed? Because she believed in Alternative (to) Medicine? Because she wanted to find a doctor who would agree to an unnecessary tonsillectomy? We can come up with dozens of possible reasons.

Comment: Re 4. She talks about the simplicity and satisfaction of Iranian medicine, and at the end of the video, her brother suggests setting up an Iranian medicine hospital in New Zealand. But these are the claims of the video. Don't expect me to back up a claim with unattainable evidence. It is wise to be sure.

Comment: Re 1. So why did I ask this question? You mean we should trust every video? Re 3: In the video at [0:26](https://youtu.be/WqvU9nJfjw0?t=26), the subtitle say something relevant.

Comment: @C.F.G Re 4: To be brutal, I don't about the opinion of a random New Zealander thinks about Iranian medicine. If Iranian medicine works, it should be subjected to repeated double-blind controlled trials, and the successful features incorporated into the body of knowledge that is modern medicine.

Comment: Re: 1: You are distorting what I said. I never suggested trusting every video.  I asked: if you think some of the video is fake, why believe any of it? The subtitles at 0:26 are awkwardly translated and I demonstrated they were untrue. Do they match the original Farsi?

Comment: Re Re 4: I did not say that Iranian medicine is good or bad. (Did I say?) I said that she explain how an Iranian doctor treated her son's illness with the lowest cost and with a simple and easy method, while one of the doctors said that we should pierce his stomach. I said this because you gave dozens of possible answers to why she traveled to Iran for treatment? Anyway, yes, the subtitle matches the original Farsi, but the original Farsi is the narration of the Iranian side.

Comment: @C.F.G: You said "I am sure of the simplicity and power of Iranian-Islamic traditional medicine". I edited it out because it wasn't relevant to the claim, and I was afraid the answers would get distracted into trying to show it was right or wrong. The quoted letters of the doctors made much less invasive recommendations (while reporting the mother was requesting surgery on the boys tonsils), so I am not sure what the stomach piercing claim is about. I do not know what the Iranian doctor's treatment was, so I can't comment on that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that appropriate edit. In video the presenter say for transferring food into the son's stomach, doctors offered to drill his stomach. this is called PEG Tube surgery in medicine. But the Iranian doctor's treatment was decoction of a medicinal plant (that she shows that medicinal plant to the camera in the video)+ a little honey.